# Chi square test of goodness of fit with unknown parameters

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, maximum-likelihood, goodness-of-fit

$\chi^2$ test of good fit for multinomial distribution with known parameters uses test statistics 
$$ 
\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\left( X_k -n p_k^0 \right)^2}{np_k^0},
$$
where $K$ is number of categories, $X_k$ is number of observations in category $k$, $p_k^0$ is probability of category $k$ under null hypothesis (these parameters are known) and $n$ is number of observations. This test statistic under null hypothesis converges in distribution to $\chi^2_{K-1}$ distribution.

In case of unknown parameters, we assume that probabilities $p_1^0, \dots , p_K^0$ depend on (the form of dependence is known) parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$, where $d < K$. We can estimate these parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$ from observed data by the minimum $\chi^2$ method, then use them to calculate estimates of parameters $p_1^0, \dots , p_K^0$ and plug this estimates in the same formula. Our test statistic in this case is
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\left( X_k -n p_k^0(\widehat{\theta_1}, \dots ,\widehat{\theta_d}) \right)^2}{np_k^0(\widehat{\theta_1}, \dots ,\widehat{\theta_d})}.
$$
In this case the test statistics under null hypothesis converges in distribution to $\chi^2_{K-d-1}$ distribution.

My question is: If we estimate parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$ by the maximum likelihood method then these estimates $\widehat{\theta_1}, \dots , \widehat{\theta_d}$ converge in probability to values of real parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$ and thus if we plug them in the formula instead of estimates obtained by minimum $\chi^2$ method then the convergence in distribution does not change (some other assumptions are needed but let's say they are all satisfied), that is this statistic converges in distribution to $\chi^2_{K-1}$ distribution. We obtain the same result with all other consistent estimates of parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$. Is it right then that estimates of parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$ obtained by the minimum $\chi^2$ method are not consistent or is there a mistake? How powerful is test derived using maximum likelihood estimates of parameters $\theta_1, \dots , \theta_d$ in comparison with the test derived by the minimum $\chi^2$ method?

Edit:

If we assume that probabilities $p_1^0, \dots , p_K^0$ depend on uknown parameters smoothly, than $p_i^0 (\widehat{\theta_1}, \dots ,\widehat{\theta_d})$ for $i \in \{ 1, \dots , K \}$ are consistent estimators of true probabilities $p_1^0, \dots , p_K^0$ (follows from Continuous mapping theorem). Then we can write the test statistics as
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{X_k^2}{n p_k^0 (\widehat{\theta_1}, \dots ,\widehat{\theta_d})} - 2X_k + n p_k^0 (\widehat{\theta_1}, \dots ,\widehat{\theta_d})
$$
and apply Slutsky's theorem on all addends separately so we know that expression converges in distribution to the same asymptotic distribution as expression
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\left( X_k -n p_k^0 \right)^2}{np_k^0}.
$$
So the asymptotic distribution of test statistic in case of unknown parameters should be chi-square with $K-1$ df. Is there a mistake?

Comment: Minimum chi-square is consistent. Some of your assertions don't appear to be correct; the asymptotics should be the same for minimum chi square and ML if you're using the same data for both -- if you are quoting sources for those statements you should indicate who said what where. I imagine you're reading things for two different situations. (Also, are your original data discrete or are you discretizing them after estimation?)

Comment: @Glen_b I read lots of different sources and all say that if parameters are know the asymptotic distribution of test statistic is chi-square with K-1 degrees of freedom and if parameters are unknown (estimated by minimum chi-square) then the asymptotic distribution is chi-square with K-d-1 degrees of freedom ([link](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chigf.htm)). You say minimum-chi square estimates are consistent, so I think that the asymptotic distribution of test statistics should by chi-square with K-1 degrees of freedom in both cases. I think this follows from Slutsky's theorem

Comment: It's true that if the parameters are known the df should be $k-1$. However, it doesn't follow  that "the asymptotic distribution of test statistics should be chi-square with $k-1$ degrees of freedom in both cases".

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand why we cannot apply Slutsky's theorem ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem))  and Continuous mapping theorem ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem)) to derive that df should be K-1 in case of unknown parameters (assuming we know that in case of known parameters df is equal to K-1). Can you please explain which assumptions of these two theorems are not satisfied? Thank you.

Comment: What might be wrong depends on how you're making the argument, which is why you need to make the argument first (not just name which theorems you want to use in it), before anyone can attempt to identify problems in it.

Comment: I edited the original question. I want to know if there is a mistake in my derivation. Thank you very much.